# Stirling number of first kind s(m,4)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Find a closed formula in terms of m, s(m,4)?

s(m,1) seems easy enough. Just 1 cycle. Arrange the m numbers in m! ways. Then each number can be shifted one place to right m times to get same cycle. Hence s(m,1)=(m-1)!
How to go about doing for s(m,4)? Could we do this without giving some explicit formula. I would like to understand how to do this by just counting.

Comment: Have you tried $s(m,2)$ and $s(m,3)$, to get an idea of the formulas and ideas involved?

Comment: Some hint for s(m,3)?

Comment: Let alone s(m,3), Is this right for s(m,2)? I am trying to pick a subset. If that subset length is k then I know (k-1)! and similarly (m-k-1)! for the complement set. Hence (k-1)!* (m-k-1)! for a particular subset of length k. Hence s(m,2) = $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (k-1)!* (m-k-1)!$$